# Using multiple jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, selector

This is my example code:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

And in jQuery I want to listen to both inputs change somehow like this:

```
$('#input1,#input2').change(function(){

var val1 = $('#input1').val();
var val2 = $('#input2').val();

[...some more code...]

});
```

but I just can't get it to work... Any help? Thanks in advance...

Comment: That should work fine. Have you placed your JavaScript code inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`?

Comment: This code should work. Where did you register this lines? in document.ready? Please make sure your HTML ids are 'input1' rendered in browser. Just checking view source will help

Comment: [works](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/VuEEc/) just fine.. note that the change happens when the input box loses focus. (else you should uses the key events)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What doesn't work? See http://jsfiddle.net/XYSwz/

Html

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />
<div id="result"></div>​
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input1, #input2').change(function(){
        var val1 = $('#input1').val();
        var val2 = $('#input2').val();
    
        alert(val1);
        alert(val2);
    });​
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input1,#input2').change(function(){
    var val1 = $('#input1').val();
    var val2 = $('#input2').val();
     alert(val1);//test
     alert(val2);//test
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rj6FV/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should function as is.

You could always try the `add()` function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#input1').add('#input2').change(function() {
        var val1 = $('#input1').val();
        var val2 = $('#input2').val();

    });
});
```

If your elements are created dynamically, you'll need to use the `on()` or `live()` function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#input1').add('#input2').on('change', function() {
        var val1 = $('#input1').val();
        var val2 = $('#input2').val();

    });
});
```