# how to add two selectors values on change function in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to calculate the values from two select box with values changing and        multiplying this values and sent to another text box in jquery.

```js
$(" .my-form ").on(' change', '.box1,.box4', function() {
  var total_row = $(this).val();
  total_row *= $(this).siblings(".box2").val();
  var b = $(this).val();
  b = $(this).siblings(".box2").val();
  $(this).siblings(".answer").val(total_row + b);
  calTotal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
  <p class="text-box">
    From:
    <select id="box4" name="fromcurrency[]" class="box4" style="width:150px;">
      <option selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="65.61">United States</option>
      <option value="17.86">United Arab Emirates</option>
      <option value="46.83">Australia</option>
      <option value="CAD">Canada</option>
      <option value="CHF">Switzerland</option>
      <option value="CNY">China</option>
      <option value="DKK">Denmark</option>
      <option value="EUR">European Union</option>
      <option value="GBP">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Special Administrative Region</option>
      <option value="INR">India</option>
      <option value="JPY">Japan</option>
      <option value="NOK">Norway</option>
      <option value="NZD">New Zealand</option>
      <option value="OMR">Oman</option>
      <option value="PHP">Philippines</option>
      <option value="QAR">Qatar</option>
      <option value="SAR">Saudi Arabia</option>
      <option value="SEK">Sweden</option>
      <option value="SGD">Singapore</option>
      <option value="THB">Thailand</option>

    </select>


    Product:
    <select name="size[]" id="box1" class="box1">
      <option selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="0.6">Forex Card</option>
      <option value="0.7">Currency Notes</option>
      <option value="0.5">Travellers Cheque</option>
      <option value="0.4">Wire Transfer</option>
    </select>

    Forex Amount:
    <input name="qty[]" id="box2" class="box2" type="text" value="" size="6" />Rupee Amount:
    <input name="multiply[]" id="answer" class="answer" type="text" value="" size="6" />
    <a class="add-box" href="#" style="float:right; margin-top:10px;">Add More</a>
  </p>
  <span style=" padding-left:250px;"> Total Amount Is: <input name="total" id="total" type="text" value="" size="6" class="GrandTotal" /></span>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height:35px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please vist the [help] to see how to ask questions here. For example add enough html and code for us to see and explan what does not work

Comment: ok..thanks for your notify

Comment: #mplungjan..can i get answer? change function with two selectors and add this values to other textbox

Comment: Show the HTML so we can see what is going on. - https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: If the fields are static, e.g. not dynamically added to the form and the form is not ajaxed, then you have your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931778/using-multiple-jquery-selectors

Comment: You do not have a form with class `my-form`

Comment: sorry this have <div class="my-form">

Comment: If you have 'add more' then don't use `id=` as the `id` should be unique.  It's not clear how you're adding more, but worth observing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form name="form" >
        <p class="text-box">
     From:
        <select id="box4" name="fromcurrency[]" class="box4" style="width:150px;">
            <option selected="selected">Select</option> 
            <option value="65.61">United States</option>
            <option value="17.86">United Arab Emirates</option>
            <option value="46.83">Australia</option>
            <option value="CAD">Canada</option>
            <option value="CHF">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="CNY">China</option>
            <option value="DKK">Denmark</option>
            <option value="EUR">European Union</option>
            <option value="GBP">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Special Administrative Region</option>
            <option value="INR">India</option>
            <option value="JPY">Japan</option>
            <option value="NOK">Norway</option>
            <option value="NZD">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="OMR">Oman</option>
            <option value="PHP">Philippines</option>
            <option value="QAR">Qatar</option>
            <option value="SAR">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="SEK">Sweden</option>
            <option value="SGD">Singapore</option>
            <option value="THB">Thailand</option>

        </select> 


        Product:
            <select name="size[]" id="box1" class="box1">
            <option selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="0.6">Forex Card</option>
            <option value="0.7">Currency Notes</option>
            <option value="0.5">Travellers Cheque</option>
            <option value="0.4">Wire Transfer</option>
            </select>

       Forex Amount:<input name="qty[]" id="box2" class="box2" type="text" value="" size="6"/>
       Rupee Amount:<input name="multiply[]" id="answer" class="answer" type="text" value="" size="6" />
               <a class="add-box" href="#" style="float:right; margin-top:10px;">Add More</a>
                </p>
       <span style=" padding-left:250px;"> Total Amount Is: <input name="total" id="total" type="text" value="" size="6" class="GrandTotal" /></span>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height:35px;" /> 
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you need something like this

```js
function calTotal() {
    var total_row = $("#box4").val();
    total_row *= $("#box2").val();
    $("#answer").val(total_row.toFixed(2));
}

$(function() {
  $('.box1, .box2, .box4').on('change',calTotal); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <p class="text-box">
    From:
    <select id="box4" name="fromcurrency[]" class="box4" style="width:150px;">
      <option selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="65.61">United States</option>
      <option value="17.86">United Arab Emirates</option>
      <option value="46.83">Australia</option>
      <option value="CAD">Canada</option>
      <option value="CHF">Switzerland</option>
      <option value="CNY">China</option>
      <option value="DKK">Denmark</option>
      <option value="EUR">European Union</option>
      <option value="GBP">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Special Administrative Region</option>
      <option value="INR">India</option>
      <option value="JPY">Japan</option>
      <option value="NOK">Norway</option>
      <option value="NZD">New Zealand</option>
      <option value="OMR">Oman</option>
      <option value="PHP">Philippines</option>
      <option value="QAR">Qatar</option>
      <option value="SAR">Saudi Arabia</option>
      <option value="SEK">Sweden</option>
      <option value="SGD">Singapore</option>
      <option value="THB">Thailand</option>

    </select>


    Product:
    <select name="size[]" id="box1" class="box1">
      <option selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="0.6">Forex Card</option>
      <option value="0.7">Currency Notes</option>
      <option value="0.5">Travellers Cheque</option>
      <option value="0.4">Wire Transfer</option>
    </select>

    Forex Amount:
    <input name="qty[]" id="box2" class="box2" type="text" value="" size="6" />Rupee Amount:
    <input name="multiply[]" id="answer" class="answer" type="text" value="" size="6" />
    <a class="add-box" href="#" style="float:right; margin-top:10px;">Add More</a>
  </p>
  <span style=" padding-left:250px;"> Total Amount Is: <input name="total" id="total" type="text" value="" size="6" class="GrandTotal" /></span>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height:35px;" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Original (from question)

```
$(".my-form").on('change', '.box1,.box4', function(){
    var total_row = $(this).val();
    total_row *= $(this).siblings(".box2").val();
    var b = $(this).val();
    b = $(this).siblings(".box2").val();
    $(this).siblings(".answer").val(total_row+b);
    calTotal();
});
```

The first line:

```
$(".my-form").on('change', '.box1,.box4', function() {
```

uses event delegation, so any new `.box1` or `.box4` created will still hit the event.

So we can assume the code will add new boxes in future (especially as there's a 'add more' link) - so we can't use `#id`.

The next line will take the value from the box that fired the event:

```
var total_row = $(this).val();
```

so at this point `$(this)` is *either* `.box1` *or* `.box4` - not both

then

```
var b = $(this).val();
```

same as original `total_row` - either box1 or box4

So, forget about using `$(this)` to get a value and just use it to find the sibling boxes you want, eg (as it's nowhere near clear what the functionality *should* be from the obscure control names):

```
$(".my-form").on('change', '.box1,.box4', function(){
    var total_row = $(this).siblibgs(".box1").val() * 1;
    total_row *= $(this).siblings(".box2").val() * 1;
    var b = $(this).siblings(".box").val() * 1;
    b = $(this).siblings(".box2").val() * 1;
    $(this).siblings(".answer").val(total_row+b);
    calTotal();
});
```

**I suggest you give your controls meaningful names rather than "boxN".**

From the edit, box1 = product, box2 = qty, box4 = from-currency  but most of the currency values have text, not numbers